# Viewsonic VG2427wm detected max resolution too low

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution

So I have a Viewsonic VG2427wm, which supports max resolution of 1920x1080 and I had it working at this resolution from both windows and linux PCs. Now, I need to connect it to my Dell XPS17 (L702x), which has only DP mini and HDMI, so I'm trying to connect this monitor via HDMI-to-DVI adapter (doesn't work at all) and via DP-mini-to-DVI adapter. The later works, but is limiting my max resolution to 1680x1050. Using same two adapters to connect my dell monitor works fine, so I don't suspect any of the adapters to be faulty. The driver is the latest viewsonic driver (although it's been last updated 3 years back). Any ideas, how I can force it to display it's correct native resolution?

Comment: I have a similar issue with a Viewsonic vs11349, the max resolution is 1880x1050 and it used to work in windows just fine, but in linux it works sometimes, sometimes it only detects a max res of 1280x768